# Flexbox wont vertically centre child elements of parent

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have a parent container div and some child elements however only one child element is being vertically centred. I cant figure out what i am doing incorrect. The instagramwrapper is being vertically aligned but the wrapper containing two other child elements remains up the top of the page.

html:

```
<div class="Container">
<div class="headerWrapper">
   <div> 
       <span>Information & Advice</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <span>From the daylight experts</span> 
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-carousel></app-carousel>
    <app-guides></app-guides>
</div> 
<div class="instagramWrapper">
    <app-instagram></app-instagram>
</div>
```

css:

```
  .Container {
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;     
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .wrapper {
    width: 780px;
    /* inherit parent width */
  }

  .instagramWrapper {
    width: 500px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    /* inherit parent width */
  }
```

It was my understanding that 'align-items' can be aligned in the cross axis of the current line of the flex container?

[image]

new result ^

Comment: The `flex-direction: row` rule is not necessary as that is its default value; can you show a picture of your current output and what you expect?

Comment: Please could you edit your question and use the snippet button to create a [mcve] and explain a little more what the problem is as it's unlcear which div you are expecting to be centred

Comment: updated with picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container might have height of 100%. But does it's parent have a height of 100%?

try the following:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will give the document a height of 100% of the viewport, so that the .Container gets 100% of the document.

And both of your inner Elements (instafeed and the column on the left) will be positioned differently, depending on their size.

Comment: aww dammit well spotted

Comment: By doing this they are both now centred however they are different heights so dont appear to be lined up correctly, what do i do to ensure they stay in line. picture attached above of the new result

Comment: I strongly recommend to read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. Try it with align-items: baseline; Your items have a different height, that is how different heights are handled when they are centered. Otherwise you will need to put another wrapper around your elements. And this wrapper is positioned in the center